# The appropriate way to add a login endpoint in OpenAPI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, openapi

I'm using [OpenApi](https://springdoc.org/) for Spring Boot application and I have authorization logic with JWT. The authorization request at `/api/v1/login` is intercepted and JSON is returned with the user token:

```json
{
    "Bearer": "token for user"
}
```

Security implementation responsible for capturing logins:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
     @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException {                      
        // handler returns body JSON with JWT                                        
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // ...

    JsonObjectAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        var authFilter = new JsonObjectAuthenticationFilter();
        authFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(restAuthenticationSuccessHandler );
        authFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(RestAuthenticationFailureHandler );
        authFilter.setAuthenticationManager(super.authenticationManager());
        authFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/v1/login"); // <- custom login URL
        return authFilter;
    }
}
```

It works fine, I don't have to put a separate `/api/v1/login` endpoint in the controller, so it is not taken into account when creating OpenAPI documentation. However, I want to have this endpoint documented and accessible from there as follows:

[image: 1]

My first idea was to just create an interface to add appropriate annotations (assume `BearerToken` and `AuthCredentials` are my tranfer objects in correct format):

```java
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/login")
@Tag(name = "login")
interface LoginController {

    @PostMapping
    BearerToken login(@RequestBody AuthCredentials authCredentials);
}
```

However Spring does not register the interface as a beana, an implementation has yet to be provided, so OpenAPI does not add an entry to the documentation. So I turned the interface into a normal class:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/login")
@Tag(name = "login")
class LoginController {

    @PostMapping
    public BearerToken login(@RequestBody AuthCredentials authCredentials){
        return new BearerToken();
    }
}
```

Documentation is generated correctly, but I have a problem with this method. The implementation of the `login()` method **suggests a completely different behavior than what actually takes place** underneath in `onAuthenticationSuccess()`.

Therefore, I am looking for a different way to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per OpenAPI implementation, there is a class `OpenAPIService` which has a `build()` method that does the following:

```
    this.mappingsMap.putAll(this.context.getBeansWithAnnotation(RestController.class));
    this.mappingsMap.putAll(this.context.getBeansWithAnnotation(RequestMapping.class));
    this.mappingsMap.putAll(this.context.getBeansWithAnnotation(Controller.class));
```

The reason as to why what you want to achieve is not possible is that OpenAPI library relies on Spring annotations that I provided above and has no knowledge of custom ant matcher paths like the one you added:

```
  JsonObjectAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        var authFilter = new JsonObjectAuthenticationFilter();
        authFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(restAuthenticationSuccessHandler );
        authFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(RestAuthenticationFailureHandler );
        authFilter.setAuthenticationManager(super.authenticationManager());
        authFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/v1/login"); // <- custom login URL
        return authFilter;
    }
```

Usually in production-ready applications developers write their own `/authenticate` API that checks username + password pair against a datasource (mySQL/postgreSQL/other).
This `/authenticate` API would be whitelisted so that security is not required to attempt login (some people store number of attempts per IP in Redis in case they want to block people from bruteforcing the password).

All other APIs would have to go through `public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends AuthenticationFilter {` which simply validates the token and allows request to continue (if token is valid).

If you need more hints let me know.

Comment: Okay, so problem with my solustion is in authentication implementation and I should implement that part in "standard" way, by using `@RestController` and service with logic, which now I have inside `RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler`

Comment: Yes, correct. On all projects I worked on authentication was done in a similar way that I explained above (small and big projects) so I'd suggest using a similar approach.